# Nims game python

Tags: python

I was trying a tutorial from youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqsZ8DD6WHU . And my code doesn't work as it suppose to. Can somebody explain why? Thanks

```
code
```

```
nims = 21

player = 1



while True:

    print("The number left:", nims)

    print ("player", player) 
    
    while True:     
        move = input("Put a number: ")
        if move in [1,2,3] and move > nims:
            break
        
        print("Illegal move")
    

    nims = nims - int(move)

            # Show how many left      
            #if nims == 0:

            #    print("not allow to take all")

    if nims == 1:
        print("Player", player, "Lose")
        break

    if player == 1:
        player = 2
    else:
        player = 1

print("Game Over")
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work like it supposed to". What exactly happens when and how exactly is it different form what you expect?

Comment: Try replacing `if move in [1,2,3] and move > nims:` with  `if move in [1,2,3] and move < nims:`, because that is surely what you want for the move to be legal.

Comment: @mousetail  This happens: It's going in second while loop 
Put a number: 2
Illegal move
Put a number: 3
Illegal move
Put a number: 4
Illegal move
Put a number: 6
Illegal move
Put a number:

Comment: You need to cast the input to an integer `int(input())`

Comment: @mousetail Sweet! It works! Thanks

Comment: @mousetail Can you explain why my kind of error happened? if you don't mind.

Comment: input() returns a string, next you check if is equal to the number 1 (or 2 or 3) but it can never be because a string can never be equal to an integer

Comment: @mousetail Sweet! thanks